# Is there any way to make a web page slightly glow without CSS box-shadow?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, canvas

### I'm trying to code a tough interface feature *performantly*

I'm trying to code an interface to which I apply a broad, faint glow like this (dark example, sorry):

[image]

---

### What I've tried so far

I've considered `outer-glow`, `filter`, and `canvas` solutions, but none of them seem to offer a viable, performant result:

- **outer-glow:** Would technically do exactly what I want.

**BUT** *severely* damages performance, especially with wide glows.

- **filters:** I only know of the blur filter for doing this, except blur isn't really glow - it would blur edges severely. It would technically do exactly what I want IF I were to duplicate the DOM, blur the duplicate, place that in front of the actual DOM, apply low opacity, `pointer-events:none`, and keep it in sync with the non-blurred DOM via JavaScript.

**BUT** doubling the DOM and replicating all events within the DOM would not only be a big mess, it would likely damage performance in a serious way.

- **canvas:** I could write the DOM to an overlayed low opacity canvas and blur that.

**BUT** (*unless there's a way to read the whole window render and feed that into canvas directly*) this involves a complex, faulty (security roadblocks and limited support for the functionality) process of rendering all the DOM elements as SVG and I would still have to keep that canvas version of the DOM in sync with the actual DOM, which will be a mess.

---

### My question

So I'm out of ideas. **Is there any way for me to make my interface glow, in a performant way?**

I'm not very hopeful on this, but I did want to reach out and see if something I hadn't thought of with filters, canvas, or some other trick would make this glow effect possible in a web application while preserving performance.

Comment: You could add a transparent image or add a colored absolute positioned `<div>` then set the CSS `opacity:0.5; filter:alpha(opacity=50);` or something.

Comment: @PHPglue When the interface transforms, transitions, scrolls, etc, that glow on top would not be able to correspond with the actual colors or sections of the interface.. It would be like a plain single colored fog rather than a glow effect. I'm trying to correspond the glow with the actual interface colors and components.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the route you were really looking for but, it would be able to produce the result you are trying to get.  This approach would certainly be the most performant approach you could take, but of course you have to update the design.

**The design update approach**
You could approach this from the design side rather than a coding one.  So rather than coding something.  You would figure out what the final target colors are for your elements and modify your css.  You would also need to modify some images potentially.

Comment: An interesting possibility.

Comment: usually I have done this kind of thing when I have a site that a customer wants to change color schemes for a short duration or something.  so like they want their site to be shades of pink for breast cancer awareness week.  I basically just have a pink css file sitting there and swap it out for the duration of the event.  

I have also found it useful when when working with marketing/design companies that is very specific with placement and shades of colors.